# Generating keypair and storing in Keystore

Tags: c#, windows-server-2012, key-pair, sn.exe

I'm currently working on a system based on this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4940/Using-XML-Digital-Signatures-for-Application-Licen

However, in the article he uses sn.exe to generate a keypair and store it into a key container.

I'm wanting to do this on a windows server 2012 machine, with no access to sn.exe, and i cannot seem to find a way to do this, can any suggest a tool that will work with server 2012?

Cheers